# Uploading a captured image to parse (Parse object)

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, parse-platform

I am trying to develop an android application using Xamarin(c#) and parse where user will capture a pic and upload it to parse. I know how to upload a text file but as I am new to this I have no idea how to deal with an image file can anyone please help. This is how I am uploading a text file

```
byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("This is content of the text file");

                ParseFile file = new ParseFile("resume.txt", data);
                await file.SaveAsync();

            ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("GameScore");
            gameScore["score"] = 0001;
            gameScore["playerName"] = " Bob";
            gameScore["e"] = file;
            await gameScore.SaveAsync();`
```

Can anyone please help me with this problem.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Parse has an entire [section of docs](https://parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#files) devoted to dealing with files.

```
// File is in System.IO
byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(path_to_your_image);
ParseFile file = new ParseFile(name_of_your_file, data);
await file.SaveAsync();

// link your file object to your Parse object
gameScore["image"] = file;
```

Update:

The docs specifically say

> It's important that you give a name to the file that has a file
>   extension. This lets Parse figure out the file type and handle it
>   accordingly. So, if you're storing PNG images, make sure your filename
>   ends with .png.

Comment: I have tried this but getting an exception. I have explained my problem above. Please help

Comment: when you name your file in new ParseFile(), give it an appropriate extension so Parse can determine the file type.

Comment: I have added an extension ParseFile file = new ParseFile ("imgfl.jpg", myfile); but still getting an exception  here is my exception http://pastebin.com/P8Lwm1BW

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I got the solution. my code was correct but there was a problem with my parse credentials.